# Incorrect response from post request with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Search url - http://aptaapps.apta.org/findapt/Default.aspx?UniqueKey=.

Need to get data for the zipcode(10017)
Sending post requests but I receive the search page(response from the search url) but not the page with results.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element


search_url = "http://aptaapps.apta.org/findapt/Default.aspx?UniqueKey="
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(search_url)
post_page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
try:
    target_value = post_page.find("input", id="__EVENTTARGET")["value"]
except TypeError:
    target_value = ""

try:
    arg_value = post_page.find("input", id="__EVENTARGUMENT")["value"]
except TypeError:
    arg_value = ""

try:
    state_value = post_page.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
except TypeError:
    state_value = ""

try:
    generator_value = post_page.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
except TypeError:
    generator_value = ""

try:
    validation_value = post_page.find("input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]
except TypeError:
    validation_value = ""

post_data = {
            "__EVENTTARGET": target_value,
            "__EVENTARGUMENT": arg_value,
            "__VIEWSTATE": state_value,
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": generator_value,
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": validation_value,
            "ctl00$SearchTerms2": "",
            "ctl00$maincontent$txtZIP": "10017",
            "ctl00$maincontent$txtCity": "",
            "ctl00$maincontent$lstStateProvince": "",
            "ctl00$maincontent$radDist": "1",
            "ctl00$maincontent$btnSearch": "Find a Physical Therapist"
            }

headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Content-Length": "3025",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Host": "aptaapps.apta.org",
        "Origin": "http://aptaapps.apta.org",
        "Proxy-Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Referer": "http://aptaapps.apta.org/findapt/default.aspx?UniqueKey=",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
        }

post_r = session.post(search_url, data=post_data, headers=headers)
print(post_r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

try to replace:

```
post_r = session.post(search_url, data=post_data, headers=headers)
```

to:

```
post_r = session.post(search_url, json=post_data, headers=headers)
```

Long Answer:

For POST method, there are many kinds of data types to post in. Such as `form-data`, `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `application/json`, `file` and etc.

You should know what is the type of the post data. There is a brilliant chrome plugin called [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=zh-CN). You can use it to try different data type and find what is the correct one.

After you find, use the correct parameter key in `requests.post`, the parameter `data` if for `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded`. The parameter `json` is for json format. You can reference the document of requests to know more about the parameter.

Comment: Hi Kingname, thanks for your answer.
The data type is "x-www-form-urlencoded" so the parameter is correct but the code doesn't work.

P.S.: I've tried to change it to json. Doesn't work.

Comment: OK，
1. remove `"Content-Length": "3025"` from your headers. and retry.

2. if step 1  still can not work, please install postman, and try to use it to find if it can make the correct request.

Comment: 1. Doesn't work.
2. I've installed it but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @GiveItAwayNow if so, it means that the url or the headers or the data you post is(are) not correct. it is out of python's business. please research the website, use fiddler or charles to capture packets to find the solutions.

Comment: @GiveItAwayNow all in all, only when you make it work in postman, can you solve the problem in python.